# Alternative to using Excel DataSink with VLOOKUP in SoapUI Test Case?

Tags: soapui

I currently have the following test case in SoapUI NG Pro where the aim is to create new records in a database table (Product) that includes a foreign key to another table (ProductType). I currently have the test setup as follows:

1. JDBC DataSource that retrieves the IDs and Descriptions of records in ProductType table
2. DataSink that saves these IDs and Descriptions to an Excel workbook in sheet 1. In sheet 2 I have a list of Product Names and Product Types that I want to use in a POST. I then use VLOOKUP to populate the ProductTypeId in sheet 2 based on the values in sheet 1
3. DataSource Loop
4. Excel DataSource that pulls from sheet 2 of the workbook
5. POST REST Request that uses the Name and ProductTypeId values from data source
6. DataSource Loop

This works perfectly well for the moment however I have 2 concerns going forward:

1. The SoapUI project is version controlled using Visual Studio, the Excel workbook should really be checked in along with the project however would mean that I need to check out the Excel workbook every time I wanted to run the DataSink step.
2. When the project moves to another environment, the server may not have an instance of Excel

I would therefore like to keep all data sources contained within SoapUI (e.g. use the Grid type)

I have played around with using Grid data sources and using Property Transfer steps but I'm stuck.

Unfortunately I don't have any previous experience of writing groovy scripts and only know a little bit about XPath.

I am using SoapUI NG Pro 2.0.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it sounds like you're almost there with moving the data source in grid instead of external file.  What is the part you're actually stuck with?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the reply, my issue is that I am reliant on the VLOOKUP in the Excel workbook in order to map a ProductTypeId to the Product. In Sheet 2, the 3 columns I have are ProductName, ProductTypeId and ProductType. ProductTypeId is the column with the VLOOKUP and it compares ProductType to the data in Sheet 1 populated during the DataSink. I need to find a way within SoapUI to replicate the VLOOKUP.

Comment: Can you combine the Product, Description, ProductTypeId into a single row in some sort of a file?   Do the values change often?  Even with the foreign key, you should be able to create a query that puts the three values into a single row.  If you can do that, you ditch the data sink and Excel data source.  You could then keep the OBDC step and not have to start all that test data within your SopaUI project.

Comment: @Chris The Product and ProductType that I wish to assign to the product won't change however the ProductTypeId will change often. The Ids are all GUIDs so will always be different. We are using POST REST requests to populate the ProductType table prior to this test. In the POST that creates Products I need to supply the ProductTypeId rather than description.

Comment: Sorry for seeming to be a bit dim, I just wanted to understand a bit more.  You could add another JDBC step that does the lookup for you.  I'll add an answer with some pseudo steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Excel, use the db.  Trying adding another jdbc step inside your loop to do the lookup...

1. JDBC DataSource that retrieves the IDs and Descriptions of records in ProductType table
2. JDBC Step that looks up the ProductType.Id based on the current Product.ProductType from step 1.
3. POST REST Request.  Get the ProductName and Product Type from Step 1 and Product Type Id from Step 2.
4. Loop

I don't know the size of the data step, so Step 2 might be a bit expensive in terms of performance, but the benefit is that you don't need any Groovy scripting nor qwill you need to store any test data within your project or in a file.

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't think I explained myself very well but I was able to adapt your approach. I ended up with 1.Grid DataSource that holds my ProductName and ProductTypeDescription, 2. Property Transfer that passes the ProductTypeDescription to step 3, 3. JDBC Request to find the ProductTypeId with a where clause that contains the ProductTypeDescription, 4. POST REST Request that uses Name from the Step 1 and Id from Step 3, 5. Loop

Comment: Good stuff.  As long as it helped.